# Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information. in react native expo

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I am trying to create production build in expo using `eas build -p android --profile production` but from days I am getting the same error and I can't find the solution on the whole internet as much as I have explored, and this is my last hope please help me.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "base",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@iabtcf/core": "^1.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~49.0.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "^2.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.11",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^11.6.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

the error log of the run gradlew:

this image resolution is good enough you can zoom in it enough times to see the whole log text crystal clear, hope this helps

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-JMhLi3Lq0gJ92Ky_ZHAdcDT3eUTY-p/view?usp=sharing